# On the usage of Java equality operator

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

```
class StringTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str1 = "Hi there";
String str2 = new String("Hi there");
System.out.println(str1 == str2);
System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));
}
```

The output is coming out:

```
                          False
                          true
```

Why the first output is false even when the str1 and str2 appear to be equal?

Answer (score 6):

`==` compares content of variables. (You know this very well from `intA == intB`.)

A `String` variable contains a *reference* to a `String` object, so `==` will compare references.

After

```
String str1 = "Hi there";
String str2 = new String("Hi there");
```

`str1` and `str2` will refer to different string objects, thus contain different references, so `str1 == str2` will yield `false`.

`str1.equals(str2)` on the other hand will compare the objects that `str1` and `str2` refers to, which, as you have noted, yields `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Because if you use `new` operator it create a new reference in memory.

> == compares references of both object which are not same.
>
> use equals to compare contents.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to aioobe's answer: you should actually compare objects using the equals method. The == operator on objects is going to compare if the reference of both objects points to the same memory address.

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares `object reference contents` i.e. `str1` and `str2` and not `object contents` while `equals()` does compare `object contents` i.e `(objects pointed by str1 and str2)`

Also check this :

```
String str1 = "Hi there";
String str3 = "Hi there";
```

> str1 == str3 => true

This is because JVM handles string literals in different way. Check [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-string-literal-pool/3)

Answer (score 0):

In java when you create objects with `new` keyword they are created in heap at some location .

Even if you create third reference variable `str3` with `new` then also it will give you false if compare reference with `str2`

```
String str1 = "Hi there";
String str2 = new String("Hi there");
String str3 = new String("Hi there");

 str2==str3 gives you false
```

So when you `compare` the values of `object`s use `equals` rather than `reference` .